# Reference request: infinitary Ramsey theory

Tags: discrete-mathematics, reference-request, set-theory, ramsey-theory, infinitary-combinatorics

I was reading about the (various) infinite versions of Ramsey's theorem, and stumbled across a text containing a proof of the Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem using it:
[image: Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem using Ramsey's theorem]

Unfortunately, I forgot where I found this article. It explained the whole topic very well and stated Ramsey's (infinite) theorem in a very clear way.

1. Does anyone recognize this text by chance? I searched this for a very long time.
2. I'd be grateful for similar reading recommendations; that is, "set-theoretic" approach to the infinite Ramsey theorem and infinite graphs in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is from p. $15$ of the *Forcing Summer School Lecture Notes* by Spencer Unger, which are available in two slightly different versions [here](http://homepages.math.uic.edu/%7Eshac/forcing/forcing2014.pdf) and [here](https://www.math.toronto.edu/sunger/ucla/LogicSummerSchool/ForcingNotes.pdf). I found them by searching for:

> "by ramsey's theorem there is an infinite"  bolzano "whenever we"

I can see why you might not have found them – “whenever we define a coloring we think” seems like the most unique phrase to search for, but if you include “define” in the search it doesn’t return any hits; it looks as if the ‘ﬁ’ ligature messes up the search.

Comment: Nice searching technique! I tried various forms